# Replace one character with other in tab separated file

Tags: perl

Hi I want to replace all the . ( dots) by -1 in tab separated file.

```
.   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .
.   0.4012  0.359026    0.3616  0.246   0.4324
.   0.6795  0.60024 0.4713  0.6171  0.7386
.   0.6863  0.614018    0.5227  0.6131  0.7376
.   .   .   .   .   .
.   0.2044  0.210264    0.1936  0.2192  0.2376
.   0.2043  0.210064    0.1929  0.2183  0.2376
.   0.9852  0.984625    0.9425  1   1
.   .   0.10603 0.1127  0.127   0.0427
.   0.6934  0.709864    0.8222  0.6944  0.664
.   0.0219  0.0213658   0.0015  0.0397  0.0219
.   .   .   .   .   .
```

How ever I dont want to replace the dots present along with the numbers i.e. 0.4012 or 0.359.

I tried this code

```
perl -p -i.backup -e 's/". /-1/g' .\abc.txt
```

but It didn't work

Output I got was

```
.   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .
.   0.4012  0.359026    0.3616  0.246   0.4324
.   0.6795  0.60024 0.4713  0.6171  0.7386
.   0.6863  0.614018    0.5227  0.6131  0.7376
.   .   .   .   .   .
.   0.2044  0.210264    0.1936  0.2192  0.2376
.   0.2043  0.210064    0.1929  0.2183  0.2376
.   0.9852  0.984625    0.9425  1   1
.   .   0.10603 0.1127  0.127   0.0427
.   0.6934  0.709864    0.8222  0.6944  0.664
.   0.0219  0.0213658   0.0015  0.0397  0.0219
.   .   .   .   .   .
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given the tags in your question, I'd expect to see work-so-far in bash, awk and sed. I recommend you pick just one tool for this problem. That said, Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. If you have attempted to write something and have some difficulties, then show what you have done and ask a specific question.
Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips. If you just want free work done then StackOverflow isn't the place for such requests.

Comment: I tried perl -p -i.backup -e 's/". /-1/g' .\abc.txt

Comment: If you tried things, they should be IN YOUR QUESTION. And if you're attempting to get help with your perl code, add the [tag:perl] tag, and remove the others.

Comment: Thanks ghoti. I am new at this stuff. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sub(/^\.$/,"-1",$i)}} 1' Input_file
```

Change `awk` to `awk -F"\t"` AND `Input_file` to `OFS="\t" Input_file` in case of your Input_file is having delimiter as TAB and you want to have output in TAB format too.

Answer (score 3):

Your perl isn't *too* far off.

Remember that the substitute format's command is `s/pattern/replacement/flags`, just as it is in `sed`. The pattern is a [regular expression](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), where a single dot translates to "any single character".  To match a *literal* dot, you need to escape it with a backslash, or put it in square brackets.

```
perl -p -i.backup -e 's/\.([^0-9])/-1\1/g' abc.txt
```

This matches literal dots that are followed by something other than a numeral, and replaces them with your replacement string, along with whatever non-numeral character was matched (`\1`).  Perl appears to consider the null at the end of the line to be a non-numeral, which allows the dots at the end of the line to be replaced as well.

Note that in perl, you could also replace `[^0-9]` with `[^\d]` or `\D`, and `\1` with `$1`. But the former only works in perl and (some) GNU tools, and the latter is not the most widespread notation amongst command line tools. Personally, I'd rather keep my regexes and replacements more portable, so that if I were to switch from perl to, say, awk, I wouldn't have to rewrite so much code.

For example:

```
gawk '{$0=gensub(/\.([^0-9])/,"-1\1","g")}1' abc.txt > ,$$ && mv ,$$ abc.txt
```

or

```
sed -i.backup -Ee 's/\.([^0-9])/-1\1/g' abc.txt
```

Portability is generally a good thing, if you can manage it.

Comment: or `\D` instead of `[^0-9]` and `[^\d]`.. and `$1` is preferred in replacement section instead of `\1` ... `\d` isn't supported by GNU sed..

Comment: @Sundeep, thanks, good to know. I don't run any systems with GNU sed on them.